# Best Polynomial Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I was reading a proof of
[image]

It goes as follows
[image]

where
[image]

What I am struggling with is the application of corollary 8.3. In particular, I do not understand why $a$ not being in this set implies this inequality.

I see that the author wishes $K>1$ so that we have, uniformly,
$$
\| \sum_{j=0}^n a_j t^j\|_\infty \geq \epsilon_n.
$$
I have also identified that
$$
F(0) = \|f\|_\infty.
$$
So the Corollary is saying that
$$
F(a) \geq \epsilon_n - \| f\|_\infty.
$$
How does this tell us that
$$
F(a) \geq F(0)?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon_n>0$ be the positive number from the corollary. Fix $K>2\|f\|_\infty/\epsilon_n$. Suppose that $a\notin [-K,K]^{n+1}$. Let $P=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jt^j$. Let $Q=P/K$. Since $a\notin [-K,K]^{n+1}$, at least one of the coefficients of $Q$ has absolute value at least $1$. So $\|Q\|_\infty \geqslant \epsilon_n$. Then $\|P\|_\infty \geqslant \epsilon_n K>2\|f\|_\infty$. Therefore $$F(a)\geqslant \|P\|_\infty-\|f\|_\infty > 2\|f\|_\infty-\|f\|_\infty=F(0).$$